# Attaching Files to Email in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, url, attachment

How do I attach a file located on Web URL to an email using google app engine (Python)?

I have the file located at say: http://www.abc.com/files/file.pdf

I want to attach this to an email and send it to a user on app engine. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send attachment you have to fill the attachment field of an email message with a list of two-value tupless containing the file name and the file content. From [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments.html)

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import mail  

url = "http://www.abc.com/files/file.pdf" 
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)

if result.status_code == 200: 
  document = result.content

mail.send_mail(sender="youremail@yourdomain.com",
               to="receiver@hisdomain.com",
               subject="The file you wanted",
               body="Here is the file you wanted",
               attachments=[("The file name.pdf", document)])
```

Comment: How do you add the attachment if you have the PDFs already uploaded to your project?