# how to attach a pdf in google app engine python send_mail function?

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I cannot find any example on how to attach files(pdf) that are within my root folder of the site in python (google app engine) send_mail function.

```
 url_test = "https://mywebsite.com/pdf/test.pdf"
      test_file = urlfetch.fetch(url_test)

      if test_file.status_code == 200:
            test_document = test_file.content
      mail.send_mail(sender=EMAIL_SENDER,
                  to=['test@test.com'],
                  subject=subject,
                  body=theBody,
                  attachments=[("testing",test_document)])
```

Decided to try it with EmailMessage:

```
 message = mail.EmailMessage( sender=EMAIL_SENDER, 
 subject=subject,body=theBody,to=['myemail@gmail.com'],attachments= 
 [(attachname, blob.archivoBlob)])
 message.send()
```

The above blob attachment is successfully sending however attaching a file with relative path always says "invalid attachment"

```
 new_file = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + 
 '/../pages/pdf/test.PDF').read()

 message = mail.EmailMessage( sender=EMAIL_SENDER, 
 subject=subject,body=theBody,to=['myemail@gmail.com'],attachments= 
 [('testing',new_file )])
 message.send()
```

In debugging I have also tried to see if the file is being read by doing this:

```
 logging.info(new_file)
```

It seems to be reading the file as it outputs some unicode characters

Please help why am I not able to attach a PDF while I can attach a blob

Comment: Are you running on Standard or Flexible environment?

Comment: @LundinCast running standard environment

Comment: Since the output of logging new_file is some unicode characters and not the actual content of the PDF, it implies the issue is not necessarily about the attachment of the PDF to the send_mail function(). It seems to me that the file is not being read appropriately from the location. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mail-with-headers-attachments?csw=1#attachments_and_multipurpose_internet_mail_extensions_mime_types) explains the expected file types.

Comment: Also, when calling the attachments, the File type has to be indicated on the file title, for example attachments= 
 [('testing.pdf',new_file )]). View this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394397/attaching-files-to-email-in-app-engine#answer-3397388)

Comment: @oakinlaja thx! that was the problem! i forgot to mention the ".pdf" extension. It worked after that

Comment: Great to know. I will add that as an Answer

Answer (score 0):

When calling the attachments, the File type has to be indicated on the file title, for example attachments= [('testing.pdf',new_file )]). View this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394397/attaching-files-to-email-in-app-engine#answer-3397388)